# Passing the class as a default argument for its method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Here is the minimal `Point` class needed for this question.

```
 class Point:
      def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
           self.x = x
           self.y = y
      def dist_from(self, point = Point(0, 0)):
           return ((self.x-point.x)**2 + (self.y-point.y)**2)**0.5
```

I want the `dist_from` method to return the distance from origin if no point is passed. And since method overloading is not possible, I decided to pass a `Point` object (the origin) as the default value.
But I am missing something very fundamental.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Naveen\Desktop\temp.py", line 26, in <module>
    class Point:
  File "C:\Users\Naveen\Desktop\temp.py", line 32, in Point
    def dist_from(self, point = Point(0, 0)):
NameError: name 'Point' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

Default values are expressions that *get evaluated* when the function object is compiled. The look-up for `Point` will fail since the class named `Point` hasn't been created at that point.

This can be side stepped by supplying a default value of `None` for the default and act on that fact inside the method body (where the name `Point` has been defined:

```
def dist_from(self, point = None):
      if point is None:
          point = type(self)(0, 0)  # Could do Point(0, 0)
      return (self.x*point.x + self.y*point.y)**0.5
```

I'm using `type(self)` here instead of `Point` so as to not hard-code the class name in there.